# How to fix truetyphography plugin in Joomla [é => e]

Tags: joomla

I'm using truetypography plugin on my site. It's great for hyphenation (my site has 3 columns, so its necessary), but for some reason, in polish language file, changes several "e" into "é". Of course it happens on the go while displaying, so db and admin part of joomla looks ok.

Now I'm using something like this in jQuery to fix it:
$("#content").html($("#content").html().replace("é", "e"));

But I would like to fix the cause, not cover the output.

Any ideas on how to fix it?
Any suggestions?