# jQuery clears whole page in joomla leaving only links

Tags: jquery

I wrote yesterday a question concerning weird character in joomla truetypography:
[How to fix truetyphography plugin in Joomla [é => e]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423801/how-to-fix-truetyphography-plugin-in-joomla-e-e)

I also wrote, that im using this code to fix it:
//$("#content").html($("#content").html().replace("é", "e"));

But just now i found out, that while on some pages it wors just fine, on other this line of code changes entire page (with head, complex template, modules and lots of content into this code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="mailto:xxx@xxx.pl">xxx@xxx.pl</a>
    <span style="display:none;"></span>
    //several links here - all mailto: that were on the page separated with such spans
  </body>
</html>
```

When i check source code, it looks ok, but when i click "inspect element" (or whatever it is in English), that's what i get.

Any ideas, why it sometimes happens?

Trawa ;)

Comment: For one, your replace will only replace the first occurrence of `é`. Secondly, you shouldn't set `.html()` as that will trash all event handlers, data bound to the elements, associated widgets etc. Thirdly, don't duplicate questions, instead edit the initial one and it will be automatically bumped to the top of the Newest list.

Comment: The solution `$("#content").html($("#content").html().replace("é", "e"));` is a bad one since it will remove all the event handers and widgets initializatios done before

Comment: Thanks for comments. Sorry for adding second topic :). Any ideas, with what can I replace html().replace?